# MS SQL Extensible Key Management Using AWS KMS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-kms, tde

1. On Azure, there is Azure Key Vault MS SQL Server Connector to store Transparent Data Encryption keys in the key vault instead of locally. Is there a solution to store on AWS KMS?

Note: I can't use AWS RDS due to some unsupported features.

2. If there isn't a AWS KMS connector, how do I go about developing one? Can't seem to find any SDK or documentation for the interfaces to be implemented.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution? We have the exact same issue.

Comment: @ShaunBowe No. Client decided not to use Transparent Data Encryption